# Noise in sine wave from op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, noise

In your experience, what could be the cause for noise in a sine wave coming out of an op-amp?

[image: Photo of oscilloscope trace 1]

[image: Photo of oscilloscope trace 2]

Comment: It looks like power supply ripple. Is your op-amp powered by a switch mode converter. Oh by the way, if you want a proper answer (rather than guesses) post a schematic of your op-amp circuit and post scope shots of power supply ripple.

Comment: Your power supply maybe a DCDC converter. Check your GND connections. Try to connect oscilloscope Gnd to DCDC converter's input Gnd not to ouput Gnd. Also Check power lines which supply voltage to your DSP board(including Opamp), if there's a similar noise on power lines, you can change your supplies or sth. else.

Answer (score 2):

The noise is at about 50MHz.

It could be caused by a digital source on the PCB or by instability in the op-amp. 50MHz is a common clock frequency for FPGAs.